# Magento 2 - How i can add customer group in webshop matrix shipping module?

Tags: magento2

I am using Webshop Matrix Module but not able to add customer group i have tried a lot by doing changes in csv and database too but no luck!

Shipping method should work only based on customer group logged & imported csv file